# How to remove array's items name?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
$arr = array ( array ( "id"   => 1,
                       "name" => "John",
                       "age" => 22 ),
               array ( "id"   => 2,
                       "name" => "Jack",
                       "age" => 30 ),
               array ( "id"   => 3,
                       "name" => "Peter",
                       "age" => 14 )
             );
```

Now I need to remove all array's item name and keep their values, Something like this:

```
$newarr = array ( array ( 1, "John",  22 ),
                  array ( 2, "Jack",  30 ),
                  array ( 3, "Peter", 14 )
             );
```

Is doing that possible?

Noted that my intent of doing that is creating a `.CSV` file according to that array.

---

**Here is my full code:**

```
public function export(Request $request){

    header('Content-Type: application/excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="export.csv"');

    $tb_name_alias = $request->tb_name;
    $convert_alias_to_table_name = array('person' => "App\\persons");
    $tb_name = $convert_alias_to_table_name[$tb_name_alias];
    $arr = $tb_name::all()->toArray();

    // here I need to remove all array's item names (I think)

    $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    foreach ( $arr as $line ) {
        $val = explode(",", $line);
        fputcsv($fp, $val);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```

**Note:** This works as well:

```
public function export(Request $request){

    header('Content-Type: application/excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="export.csv"');

    $arr = array(
        '1,John,22',
        '2,Jack,30',
        '3,Peter,14'
    );

    $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    foreach ( $arr as $line ) {
        $val = explode(",", $line);
        fputcsv($fp, $val);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: How this source array created? Is this an output of any mysql query?

Comment: @d.coder Yes exactly .. Something like this: `$arr = $tb_name::all()->toArray();`

Comment: you can use unset() http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php remove name in array.

Comment: And you are fetching it by `mysql_fetch_assoc` ?

Comment: @d.coder Nope .. I use Laravel framework .. so I use elequent.

Comment: I think you can use associated array when creating CSV

Answer (score 2):

Use fputcsv http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

It doesn't  care about the key values

If you REALLY want to remove the keys. Loop though and call array_values on the result of the array

Comment: Use fputcsv ($fp, $line ) ?

Comment: Nope .. I've tested `fputcsv($fp, $line);` but still it doesn't work ... The problem is that array. Please take a look at my update ...

Comment: What is $line going in. Can you var dump that please

Answer (score 1):

Use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) -

```
$newArr = array_map('array_values', $arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_values` instead of removing the names like this:

```
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
foreach ( $arr as $item) {
    $values = array_values($item);
    fputcsv($fp, $values);
}
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: You didn't use `$values` at at all.

Comment: Thank you .. upvote .. *(however still it doesn't work)*

Comment: What is the result ?